# Phoenix production config reloading problems

Tags: docker, elixir, docker-compose, phoenix-framework, docker-machine

I have Phoenix app which works on heroku. We want to move it to DO. We will use docker.
I try to up docker image with docker-compose on my local machine. If I do it with `MIX_ENV=dev` all is well. If I set `MIX_ENV` to `prod` I have a problem.

#### Previous prod.exs:

```
use Mix.Config

config :myapp, Myapp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "myapp.herokuapp.com", port: 443],
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")

config :logger, level: System.get_env("LOG_LEVEL") || :info

config :myapp, Myapp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"),
  pool_size: 20,
  ssl: true
```

prod.secret.exs contains only credentials for DB

#### Now:

prod.exs

```
# I changed only endpoint:
config :myapp, Myapp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  ssl: false, # I replaced previous 3 lines with this...
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")
```

#### Problem

When I run `docker-compose up --build`
It works and returns:

```
web_1  | 20:29:07.073 [info] Running Myapp.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:4000
```

But! When I do:
`$ curl $(docker-machine ip default):4000` it returns nothing...

**If I go to 192.168.99.100:4000 in browser then it redirects me to** https://myapp.herokuapp.com

Does docker save my previous config? I tried to remove all experimental images which were built when I updated Dockerfile. It didn't help:(

What's going on? Any suggestions?

P.S.
My Dockerfile

```
FROM trenpixster/elixir:1.2.5

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN mix local.hex --force
RUN mix local.rebar --force
RUN mix do deps.get
RUN touch config/prod.exs

ENV PORT 4000
ENV MIX_ENV prod

RUN mix compile

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443

ENTRYPOINT ["mix", "phoenix.server"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks @aaron-tinio for his answer. It's partially fixed my issue. The second part was in ENV variables...
System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE") does not existed in my ENV which possibly prevent changes for Phoenix ENV(I'm not sure in that). But I didn't see any notifications/exceptions/warnings:(
To catch this problem I use `MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server` from my local console(without docker). And in this situation I've seen errors(Thanks my friend - @alg).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, have you tried `mix clean`?